# How to get icecast to run on port 80

Tags: linux, icecast, internet-radio

I am having an issue with trying to get icecast to work on port 80. It works on it's default but when i try to set it to port 80 everything breaks. I have made sure that the firewall is allowing connections on port 8000 as well as port 80 and 443. I have also made sure that I uncommented and changed the changeowner section of the config.

icecast.xml (DEFAUL)

```
<icecast>
    <!-- location and admin are two arbitrary strings that are e.g. visible
         on the server info page of the icecast web interface
         (server_version.xsl). -->
    <location>Earth</location>
    <admin>icemaster@localhost</admin>

    <!-- IMPORTANT!
         Especially for inexperienced users:
         Start out by ONLY changing all passwords and restarting Icecast.
         For detailed setup instructions please refer to the documentation.
         It's also available here: http://icecast.org/docs/
    -->

    <limits>
        <clients>100</clients>
        <sources>2</sources>
        <queue-size>524288</queue-size>
        <client-timeout>30</client-timeout>
        <header-timeout>15</header-timeout>
        <source-timeout>10</source-timeout>
        <!-- If enabled, this will provide a burst of data when a client 
             first connects, thereby significantly reducing the startup 
             time for listeners that do substantial buffering. However,
             it also significantly increases latency between the source
             client and listening client.  For low-latency setups, you
             might want to disable this. -->
        <burst-on-connect>1</burst-on-connect>
        <!-- same as burst-on-connect, but this allows for being more
             specific on how much to burst. Most people won't need to
             change from the default 64k. Applies to all mountpoints  -->
        <burst-size>65535</burst-size>
    </limits>

    <authentication>
        <!-- Sources log in with username 'source' -->
        <source-password>hackme</source-password>
        <!-- Relays log in with username 'relay' -->
        <relay-password>hackme</relay-password>

        <!-- Admin logs in with the username given below -->
        <admin-user>admin</admin-user>
        <admin-password>hackme</admin-password>
    </authentication>

    <!-- set the mountpoint for a shoutcast source to use, the default if not
         specified is /stream but you can change it here if an alternative is
         wanted or an extension is required
    <shoutcast-mount>/live.nsv</shoutcast-mount>
    -->

    <!-- Uncomment this if you want directory listings -->
    <!--
    <directory>
        <yp-url-timeout>15</yp-url-timeout>
        <yp-url>http://dir.xiph.org/cgi-bin/yp-cgi</yp-url>
    </directory>
    -->

    <!-- This is the hostname other people will use to connect to your server.
         It affects mainly the urls generated by Icecast for playlists and yp
         listings. You MUST configure it properly for YP listings to work!
    -->
    <hostname>localhost</hostname>

    <!-- You may have multiple <listener> elements -->
    <listen-socket>
        <port>80</port>
        <!-- <bind-address>127.0.0.1</bind-address> -->
        <!-- <shoutcast-mount>/stream</shoutcast-mount> -->
    </listen-socket>
    <!--
    <listen-socket>
        <port>8080</port>
    </listen-socket>
    -->
    <!--
    <listen-socket>
        <port>8443</port>
        <ssl>1</ssl>
    </listen-socket>
    -->


    <!-- Global header settings 
         Headers defined here will be returned for every HTTP request to Icecast.

         The ACAO header makes Icecast public content/API by default
         This will make streams easier embeddable (some HTML5 functionality needs it).
         Also it allows direct access to e.g. /status-json.xsl from other sites.
         If you don't want this, comment out the following line or read up on CORS. 
    -->
    <http-headers>
        <header name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
    </http-headers>


    <!-- Relaying
         You don't need this if you only have one server.
         Please refer to the config for a detailed explanation.
    -->
    <!--<master-server>127.0.0.1</master-server>-->
    <!--<master-server-port>8001</master-server-port>-->
    <!--<master-update-interval>120</master-update-interval>-->
    <!--<master-password>hackme</master-password>-->

    <!-- setting this makes all relays on-demand unless overridden, this is
         useful for master relays which do not have <relay> definitions here.
         The default is 0 -->
    <!--<relays-on-demand>1</relays-on-demand>-->

    <!--
    <relay>
        <server>127.0.0.1</server>
        <port>8080</port>
        <mount>/example.ogg</mount>
        <local-mount>/different.ogg</local-mount>
        <on-demand>0</on-demand>

        <relay-shoutcast-metadata>0</relay-shoutcast-metadata>
    </relay>
    -->


    <!-- Mountpoints
         Only define <mount> sections if you want to use advanced options,
         like alternative usernames or passwords
    -->

    <!-- Default settings for all mounts that don't have a specific <mount type="normal">.
    -->
    <!-- 
    <mount type="default">
        <public>0</public>
        <intro>/server-wide-intro.ogg</intro>
        <max-listener-duration>3600</max-listener-duration>
        <authentication type="url">
                <option name="mount_add" value="http://auth.example.org/stream_start.php"/>
        </authentication>
        <http-headers>
                <header name="foo" value="bar" />
        </http-headers>
    </mount>
    -->

    <!-- Normal mounts -->
    <!--
    <mount type="normal">
        <mount-name>/example-complex.ogg</mount-name>

        <username>othersource</username>
        <password>hackmemore</password>

        <max-listeners>1</max-listeners>
        <dump-file>/tmp/dump-example1.ogg</dump-file>
        <burst-size>65536</burst-size>
        <fallback-mount>/example2.ogg</fallback-mount>
        <fallback-override>1</fallback-override>
        <fallback-when-full>1</fallback-when-full>
        <intro>/example_intro.ogg</intro>
        <hidden>1</hidden>
        <public>1</public>
        <authentication type="htpasswd">
                <option name="filename" value="myauth"/>
                <option name="allow_duplicate_users" value="0"/>
        </authentication>
        <http-headers>
                <header name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="http://webplayer.example.org" />
                <header name="baz" value="quux" />
        </http-headers>
        <on-connect>/home/icecast/bin/stream-start</on-connect>
        <on-disconnect>/home/icecast/bin/stream-stop</on-disconnect>
    </mount>
    -->

    <!--
    <mount type="normal">
        <mount-name>/auth_example.ogg</mount-name>
        <authentication type="url">
            <option name="mount_add"       value="http://myauthserver.net/notify_mount.php"/>
            <option name="mount_remove"    value="http://myauthserver.net/notify_mount.php"/>
            <option name="listener_add"    value="http://myauthserver.net/notify_listener.php"/>
            <option name="listener_remove" value="http://myauthserver.net/notify_listener.php"/>
            <option name="headers"         value="x-pragma,x-token"/>
            <option name="header_prefix"   value="ClientHeader."/>
        </authentication>
    </mount>
    -->

    <fileserve>1</fileserve>

    <paths>
        <!-- basedir is only used if chroot is enabled -->
        <basedir>/usr/share/icecast2</basedir>

        <!-- Note that if <chroot> is turned on below, these paths must both
             be relative to the new root, not the original root -->
        <logdir>/var/log/icecast2</logdir>
        <webroot>/usr/share/icecast2/web</webroot>
        <adminroot>/usr/share/icecast2/admin</adminroot>
        <!-- <pidfile>/usr/share/icecast2/icecast.pid</pidfile> -->

        <!-- Aliases: treat requests for 'source' path as being for 'dest' path
             May be made specific to a port or bound address using the "port"
             and "bind-address" attributes.
          -->
        <!--
        <alias source="/foo" destination="/bar"/>
        -->
        <!-- Aliases: can also be used for simple redirections as well,
             this example will redirect all requests for http://server:port/ to
             the status page
        -->
        <alias source="/" destination="/status.xsl"/>
        <!-- The certificate file needs to contain both public and private part.
             Both should be PEM encoded.
        <ssl-certificate>/usr/share/icecast2/icecast.pem</ssl-certificate>
        -->
    </paths>

    <logging>
        <accesslog>access.log</accesslog>
        <errorlog>error.log</errorlog>
        <!-- <playlistlog>playlist.log</playlistlog> -->
        <loglevel>3</loglevel> <!-- 4 Debug, 3 Info, 2 Warn, 1 Error -->
        <logsize>10000</logsize> <!-- Max size of a logfile -->
        <!-- If logarchive is enabled (1), then when logsize is reached
             the logfile will be moved to [error|access|playlist].log.DATESTAMP,
             otherwise it will be moved to [error|access|playlist].log.old.
             Default is non-archive mode (i.e. overwrite)
        -->
        <!-- <logarchive>1</logarchive> -->
    </logging>

    <security>
        <chroot>0</chroot>
        <!--
        <changeowner>
            <user>nobody</user>
            <group>nogroup</group>
        </changeowner>
        -->
    </security>
</icecast>
```

And here is what I changed to attempt to make it work on port 80.

```
<icecast>
    <!-- location and admin are two arbitrary strings that are e.g. visible
         on the server info page of the icecast web interface
         (server_version.xsl). -->
    <location>Earth</location>
    <admin>icemaster@localhost</admin>

    <!-- IMPORTANT!
         Especially for inexperienced users:
         Start out by ONLY changing all passwords and restarting Icecast.
         For detailed setup instructions please refer to the documentation.
         It's also available here: http://icecast.org/docs/
    -->

    <limits>
        <clients>100</clients>
        <sources>2</sources>
        <queue-size>524288</queue-size>
        <client-timeout>30</client-timeout>
        <header-timeout>15</header-timeout>
        <source-timeout>10</source-timeout>
        <!-- If enabled, this will provide a burst of data when a client 
             first connects, thereby significantly reducing the startup 
             time for listeners that do substantial buffering. However,
             it also significantly increases latency between the source
             client and listening client.  For low-latency setups, you
             might want to disable this. -->
        <burst-on-connect>1</burst-on-connect>
        <!-- same as burst-on-connect, but this allows for being more
             specific on how much to burst. Most people won't need to
             change from the default 64k. Applies to all mountpoints  -->
        <burst-size>65535</burst-size>
    </limits>

    <authentication>
        <!-- Sources log in with username 'source' -->
        <source-password>hackme</source-password>
        <!-- Relays log in with username 'relay' -->
        <relay-password>hackme</relay-password>

        <!-- Admin logs in with the username given below -->
        <admin-user>admin</admin-user>
        <admin-password>hackme</admin-password>
    </authentication>

    <!-- set the mountpoint for a shoutcast source to use, the default if not
         specified is /stream but you can change it here if an alternative is
         wanted or an extension is required
    <shoutcast-mount>/live.nsv</shoutcast-mount>
    -->

    <!-- Uncomment this if you want directory listings -->
    <!--
    <directory>
        <yp-url-timeout>15</yp-url-timeout>
        <yp-url>http://dir.xiph.org/cgi-bin/yp-cgi</yp-url>
    </directory>
    -->

    <!-- This is the hostname other people will use to connect to your server.
         It affects mainly the urls generated by Icecast for playlists and yp
         listings. You MUST configure it properly for YP listings to work!
    -->
    <hostname>localhost</hostname>

    <!-- You may have multiple <listener> elements -->
    <listen-socket>
        <port>8000</port>
        <!-- <bind-address>127.0.0.1</bind-address> -->
        <!-- <shoutcast-mount>/stream</shoutcast-mount> -->
    </listen-socket>
    <!--
    <listen-socket>
        <port>8080</port>
    </listen-socket>
    -->
    <!--
    <listen-socket>
        <port>8443</port>
        <ssl>1</ssl>
    </listen-socket>
    -->


    <!-- Global header settings 
         Headers defined here will be returned for every HTTP request to Icecast.

         The ACAO header makes Icecast public content/API by default
         This will make streams easier embeddable (some HTML5 functionality needs it).
         Also it allows direct access to e.g. /status-json.xsl from other sites.
         If you don't want this, comment out the following line or read up on CORS. 
    -->
    <http-headers>
        <header name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
    </http-headers>


    <!-- Relaying
         You don't need this if you only have one server.
         Please refer to the config for a detailed explanation.
    -->
    <!--<master-server>127.0.0.1</master-server>-->
    <!--<master-server-port>8001</master-server-port>-->
    <!--<master-update-interval>120</master-update-interval>-->
    <!--<master-password>hackme</master-password>-->

    <!-- setting this makes all relays on-demand unless overridden, this is
         useful for master relays which do not have <relay> definitions here.
         The default is 0 -->
    <!--<relays-on-demand>1</relays-on-demand>-->

    <!--
    <relay>
        <server>127.0.0.1</server>
        <port>8080</port>
        <mount>/example.ogg</mount>
        <local-mount>/different.ogg</local-mount>
        <on-demand>0</on-demand>

        <relay-shoutcast-metadata>0</relay-shoutcast-metadata>
    </relay>
    -->


    <!-- Mountpoints
         Only define <mount> sections if you want to use advanced options,
         like alternative usernames or passwords
    -->

    <!-- Default settings for all mounts that don't have a specific <mount type="normal">.
    -->
    <!-- 
    <mount type="default">
        <public>0</public>
        <intro>/server-wide-intro.ogg</intro>
        <max-listener-duration>3600</max-listener-duration>
        <authentication type="url">
                <option name="mount_add" value="http://auth.example.org/stream_start.php"/>
        </authentication>
        <http-headers>
                <header name="foo" value="bar" />
        </http-headers>
    </mount>
    -->

    <!-- Normal mounts -->
    <!--
    <mount type="normal">
        <mount-name>/example-complex.ogg</mount-name>

        <username>othersource</username>
        <password>hackmemore</password>

        <max-listeners>1</max-listeners>
        <dump-file>/tmp/dump-example1.ogg</dump-file>
        <burst-size>65536</burst-size>
        <fallback-mount>/example2.ogg</fallback-mount>
        <fallback-override>1</fallback-override>
        <fallback-when-full>1</fallback-when-full>
        <intro>/example_intro.ogg</intro>
        <hidden>1</hidden>
        <public>1</public>
        <authentication type="htpasswd">
                <option name="filename" value="myauth"/>
                <option name="allow_duplicate_users" value="0"/>
        </authentication>
        <http-headers>
                <header name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="http://webplayer.example.org" />
                <header name="baz" value="quux" />
        </http-headers>
        <on-connect>/home/icecast/bin/stream-start</on-connect>
        <on-disconnect>/home/icecast/bin/stream-stop</on-disconnect>
    </mount>
    -->

    <!--
    <mount type="normal">
        <mount-name>/auth_example.ogg</mount-name>
        <authentication type="url">
            <option name="mount_add"       value="http://myauthserver.net/notify_mount.php"/>
            <option name="mount_remove"    value="http://myauthserver.net/notify_mount.php"/>
            <option name="listener_add"    value="http://myauthserver.net/notify_listener.php"/>
            <option name="listener_remove" value="http://myauthserver.net/notify_listener.php"/>
            <option name="headers"         value="x-pragma,x-token"/>
            <option name="header_prefix"   value="ClientHeader."/>
        </authentication>
    </mount>
    -->

    <fileserve>1</fileserve>

    <paths>
        <!-- basedir is only used if chroot is enabled -->
        <basedir>/usr/share/icecast2</basedir>

        <!-- Note that if <chroot> is turned on below, these paths must both
             be relative to the new root, not the original root -->
        <logdir>/var/log/icecast2</logdir>
        <webroot>/usr/share/icecast2/web</webroot>
        <adminroot>/usr/share/icecast2/admin</adminroot>
        <!-- <pidfile>/usr/share/icecast2/icecast.pid</pidfile> -->

        <!-- Aliases: treat requests for 'source' path as being for 'dest' path
             May be made specific to a port or bound address using the "port"
             and "bind-address" attributes.
          -->
        <!--
        <alias source="/foo" destination="/bar"/>
        -->
        <!-- Aliases: can also be used for simple redirections as well,
             this example will redirect all requests for http://server:port/ to
             the status page
        -->
        <alias source="/" destination="/status.xsl"/>
        <!-- The certificate file needs to contain both public and private part.
             Both should be PEM encoded.
        <ssl-certificate>/usr/share/icecast2/icecast.pem</ssl-certificate>
        -->
    </paths>

    <logging>
        <accesslog>access.log</accesslog>
        <errorlog>error.log</errorlog>
        <!-- <playlistlog>playlist.log</playlistlog> -->
        <loglevel>3</loglevel> <!-- 4 Debug, 3 Info, 2 Warn, 1 Error -->
        <logsize>10000</logsize> <!-- Max size of a logfile -->
        <!-- If logarchive is enabled (1), then when logsize is reached
             the logfile will be moved to [error|access|playlist].log.DATESTAMP,
             otherwise it will be moved to [error|access|playlist].log.old.
             Default is non-archive mode (i.e. overwrite)
        -->
        <!-- <logarchive>1</logarchive> -->
    </logging>

    <security>
        <chroot>0</chroot>
        <changeowner>
            <user>root</user>
            <group>root</group>
        </changeowner>
    </security>
</icecast>
```

Anything helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a moderately common use-case for Icecast and you are on the right path.
I've previously explained it e.g. here http://lists.xiph.org/pipermail/icecast/2015-February/013198.html

It boils down to (I'm assuming debian/ubuntu/… based on paths):

**Edit two lines in `/etc/default/icecast2`:**

```
USERID=root
GROUPID=root
```

**Edit the following lines in `/etc/icecast2/icecast.xml`:**

- this must be the *first* `<listen-socket>` entry:

```
    <listen-socket>
        <port>80</port>
    <listen-socket>
```

- in the security section:

```
        <changeowner>
            <user>icecast2</user>
            <group>icecast</group>
        </changeowner>
```

- for yp listings, make sure `<hostname>` resolves to your Icecast server
  (not your homepage!) and remove the `<!-- -->` around the `<directory>` section.

- start Icecast through its init script / systemd

Comment: I have such an error, any ideas: [2020-12-02  15:51:25] WARN CONFIG/_parse_root Warning, <location> not configured, using default value "Earth".
[2020-12-02  15:51:25] WARN CONFIG/_parse_root Warning, <admin> contact not configured, using default value "icemaster@localhost".
Changed groupid to 116.
Changed supplementary groups based on user: icecast2.
Changed userid to 109.

Comment: none of that sounds like an error