# Icecast port 80

Tags: icecast, internet-radio, port80

Elsewhere on Stack Overflow is a question about getting Icecast to appear on port 80, which I have read but still cannot get my server to work on port 80.

My icecast.xml has these items

```
  <!-- You may have multiple <listener> elements -->
    <listen-socket>
        <port>80</port>
    </listen-socket>

    <listen-socket>
        <port>8000</port>
    </listen-socket>

    <listen-socket>
        <port>8080</port>
    </listen-socket>

    <listen-socket>
        <port>8443</port>
        <ssl>1</ssl>
    </listen-socket>

    <listen-socket>
    <port>443</port> 
    <ssl>1</ssl>
    </listen-socket>
```

And also

```
<security>
    <chroot>0</chroot>

    <changeowner>
        <user>icecast2</user>
        <group>icecast</group>
    </changeowner>

</security>
```

This is as shown in the other answer. Although ports 8000, 8080, 8443 work, I cannot get 80 to show up.

Also should 443 be between 80 and 8000 - Do the port need to be in order? I know 80 **MUST** be first.

All of this is, as usual, to get Certbot to work.

Thanks
Tony

Comment: assuming this is a Debian or related distro, make sure you also edit `/etc/default/icecast2` to ensure the process is started with root privileges

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04.1 Thanks

Comment: # Defaults for icecast2 initscript
# sourced by /etc/init.d/icecast2
# installed at /etc/default/icecast2 by the maintainer scripts

#
# This is a POSIX shell fragment
#

# Full path to the server configuration file
CONFIGFILE="/etc/icecast2/icecast.xml"

# Name or ID of the user and group the daemon should run under
USERID=icecast2
GROUPID=icecast

Comment: ok, so please reread my answer on the other question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63444539/2648865 that's what you're missing

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the help. All working now.

So to sum up. You need to start the icecast as root and then let it swap to user icecast.

To do this edit /etc/default/icecast2 if you are using Ubuntu/debian - location may veri for other distros.

To check that it is visable on port 80 go to yourserver.domain:80 and you should see the normal Icecast web page. :8000 should also still work.